Error creating Google Meet link: Invalid conference type value
I'm trying to generate a google meet link and I'm having the error Invalid conference type value.
I creted a service and then genrated a key, downloaded it (service-account-key.json)
and now I am having this error
Error creating Google Meet link: Invalid conference type value
Here's my code:
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Path to the service account key file
const credentialsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../../utils/service-account-key.json'); 
const credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(credentialsPath, 'utf8'));

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  credentials.client_email,
  null,
  credentials.private_key,
  SCOPES,
  null
);

async function createGoogleMeetLink(training) {
  const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth });

  const event = {
    summary: training.title,
    description: training.description,
    start: {
      dateTime: new Date(training.startTime).toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Africa/Tunis',
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: new Date(training.endTime).toISOString(),
      timeZone: 'Africa/Tunis',
    },
    conferenceData: {
      createRequest: {
        requestId: uuidv4(),
        conferenceSolutionKey: {
          type: 'hangoutsMeet',
        },
      },
    },
  };

  console.log('Event to be created:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)); 

  try {

    const response = await calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: 'primary',
      resource: event,
      conferenceDataVersion: 1,
      sendUpdates: 'all', // Optional: To send updates to attendees
    });
    console.log('Created event response:', JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2));

    return response.data.conferenceData.entryPoints[0].uri; // Extracting the Meet link
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error creating Google Meet link:', err.response ? err.response.data : err);
    throw new Error('Error creating Google Meet link');
  }
} ````


Looks like you've hit https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/3234
